# Stop a service when application is in background

Tags: java, android, macos, intentservice

I'm new to android and I am creating a MAC spoofing app. I have created an IntentService to spoof the MAC address in the app every 5 seconds and it is working fine. Then I created a BaseActivity which all of my activities extend from, this is so I can detect when the app goes in the background or not, this is also working fine. I already have it so when the app is in the background, the MAC address no longer changes and goes back to its original, but instead of this I want to just stop the service when the app is in background and restart the service when the app is opened again. Here is my code so far:

BaseActivity

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class BaseActivity extends Activity {
    private static int sessionDepth = 0;
    public static boolean isInBackground = false;
    WifiManager wifiManager;
    private Intent myIntent;



    // app in foreground
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        sessionDepth++;
        isInBackground = false;

        // for MAC spoofing
        myIntent = new Intent(this, IntentService.class);
        startService(myIntent);

    }

    // app in background
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (sessionDepth > 0)
            sessionDepth--;
        if (sessionDepth == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "App is in background",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            isInBackground = true;
            Log.d("My log2", "background " + isInBackground);
            wifiManager = (WifiManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
            wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false); // restart wifi
            wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
            stopService(myIntent);
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        stopService(myIntent);
    }

    public boolean getStatus(){
        return isInBackground;
    }

}
```

IntentService

```
package edu.fiu.mpact.reuproject;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.util.Log;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;


    public class IntentService extends android.app.IntentService {
        Process p = null;
        String[] ouiList;
        Random gen = new Random();
        char[] charList = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7',
                '8', '9'};


        public IntentService() {
            super("MAC");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
            try {
                ouiList = loadOUIs();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");  // prompt for root access
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
                BaseActivity b = new BaseActivity();

                @Override
                public void run() {
                  Log.d("my log2", b.getStatus() + "");

                    try {
                        if(!b.getStatus()) {
                            changeMac();
                        }

                        Log.d("my log3", Utils2.getMACAddress("wlan0"));
                    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, 0, 5000); // changes MAC every 3 seconds



        }
        private void changeMac() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            String mac = generateMac();

            //commands to execute
            String[] cmds = {"ip link set wlan0 address " + mac};

            // execute the commands
            DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(p.getOutputStream());
            for (String tmpCmd : cmds) {
                os.writeBytes(tmpCmd + "\n");
            }

        }
        private String generateMac(){
            String s = ouiList[gen.nextInt(20847)] + ":";

            for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
                s = s + charList[gen.nextInt(16)];

                //add colon
                if(((i + 1) % 2 == 0) && i != 5){
                    s = s + ":";
                }
            }

            return s;
        }

        private String[] loadOUIs() throws IOException {
            String[] ouiList = new String[20847];

            int i = 0;
            InputStream inStream = getApplicationContext().getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.oui2);
            InputStreamReader is = new InputStreamReader(inStream);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(is);

            String word = reader.readLine();  //read first OUI
            while(word != null){             //continue until no more OUI's
                ouiList[i] = word;
                word = reader.readLine();
                i++;
            }

            return ouiList;

        }


    }
```

For some reason the service is not stopping when the app goes to background, despite my stopService() calls.

Comment: also this makes no sense whatsoever in android `BaseActivity b = new BaseActivity();` you can't create a new activity and expect it to work or to be the activity that you have running somewhere else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> For some reason the service is not stopping when the app goes to background

It stopped long before your `stopService()` call, as it stopped once `onHandleIntent()` returned, milliseconds after it was created.

What is not stopping is your `Timer`, which runs on a background thread and will continue running until you cancel it or your process terminates.

IMHO, this is an inappropriate use of `IntentService`. If you want to control the lifespan, use a `Service`, and stop background work in `onDestroy()`.